# Unable to load jQuery plugins when using requirejs & r.js optimizer

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, requirejs, amd

I'm having a bit of trouble with my the requirejs optimizer. After I run the optimizer, I get a few error messages in my build/compiled file. When running my web application without the optimize step I do not have any errors.

This is my client.js file (contains config) (coffeescript)

```
requirejs.config
  baseUrl: '/source/'
  paths:
    text:                 'lib/text'
    io:                   'lib/socket.io'
    underscore:           'lib/underscore'
    backbone:             'lib/backbone'
    jquery:               'lib/jquery'
#    almond:               'lib/almond'
    bootstrap:            'lib/bootstrap'
    bootstrapFileUpload:  'lib/bootstrap-fileupload'
    jqueryUniform:        'lib/jquery.uniform'
    jqueryBrowser:        'lib/jquery.browser'
    datatables:           'lib/jquery.dataTables'
    datatables_bootstrap: 'lib/DT_bootstrap'
  shim:
    io:
      exports: 'io'
    jquery:
      exports: 'jQuery'
    jqueryBrowser:
      deps:    ['jquery']
    jqueryUniform:
      deps:    ['jqueryBrowser', 'jquery']
    underscore:
      exports: '_'
    backbone:
      deps:    ['underscore', 'jquery']
      exports: 'Backbone'
    datatables_bootstrap:
      deps:    ['jquery', 'datatables']
    datatables:
      deps:    ['jquery']


require ['routers/router', 'backbone'], (Router, Backbone) ->
  MainRouter = new Router()
  Backbone.history.start()
```

And here is my config for the optimizer. I run the optimizer from nodejs after requiring 'requirejs' as a module.

```
  config =
    baseUrl: __dirname + '/../client/source'
    name:    'lib/almond'
    include: './client'
    optimize: 'none'
    out:     __dirname + '/../client/' + hash + '.js'
    paths:
      text:                 'lib/text'
      io:                   'lib/socket.io'
      underscore:           'lib/underscore'
      backbone:             'lib/backbone'
      jquery:               'lib/jquery'
      bootstrap:            'lib/bootstrap'
      bootstrapFileUpload:  'lib/bootstrap-fileupload'
      jqueryUniform:        'lib/jquery.uniform'
      jqueryBrowser:        'lib/jquery.browser'
      datatables:           'lib/jquery.dataTables'
      datatables_bootstrap: 'lib/DT_bootstrap'
    shim:
      bootstrap:
        exports: 'bootstrap'
      bootstrapFileUpload:
        exports: 'bootstrapUpload'
      io:
        exports: 'io'
      jquery:
        exports: 'jQuery'
      jqueryBrowser:
        deps:    ['jquery']
      jqueryUniform:
        deps:    ['jqueryBrowser', 'jquery']
      underscore:
        exports: '_'
      backbone:
        deps:    ['underscore', 'jquery']
        exports: 'Backbone'
      datatables:
        deps:    ['jquery']
      datatables_bootstrap:
        deps:    ['jquery', 'datatables']



  requirejs.optimize config, (buildResponse) ->
    js = true
    if js && css
      require './server'
  , (err) ->
    console.log 'requirejs err'
    console.log err
```

The specific error I'm seeing in chrome is:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined"

Which correlates to this snippet:

```
/* Set the defaults for DataTables initialisation */
$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
```

Any idea what might be going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I encountered the same issue. I think the reason this error occurs is because `DT_bootstrap.js` is not a AMD module while it depends on the side effects of one. In this case `jquery.dataTables.js`.

When RequireJS optimizer combines all the modules you reference into one big JS file, the raw `DT_bootstrap.js` is somewhere in the middle of it, some place after `jquery.dataTables.js`. The problem is that `DT_bootstrap.js` is evaluated immediately when your combined js file is loaded. It wants `$.fn.dataTable` to be defined when it encounters the line:

```
$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
```

Since `jquery.dataTables.js` is a AMD module it has been compiled but not evaluated yet. Only in later code where it is required as a dependency will it be evaluated, and only then will it define `$.fn.dataTable`.

I worked around this by wrapping 'DT_bootstrap.js' in a AMD module definition, like is done here: https://github.com/amdjs/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L8-L24

For example:

```
(function(root, factory) {
  // Set up DT_bootstrap appropriately for the environment.
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD
    define(['jquery', 'datatables', 'bootstrap'], function($) {
      factory($);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser globals
    factory(root.jQuery);
  }
}(this, function($) {
    // <--- original DT_bootstrap.js goes here 
}));
```

It solved the issue for me.

Comment: hi, I'm struggling on this too. But my console says that $.fn.DataTable is not a function

Comment: In this line define(['jquery', 'dataTable', 'bootstrap'] replace  'dataTable' with your variable name from requirejs path of datatables

Answer (score 0):

Peter is almost correct. The only thing he missed was that the defines must match Casey's config. So in the above answer, instead of:

```
define(['jquery', 'dataTable', 'bootstrap'], function($) ...
```

it would need to be:

```
define(['jquery', 'datatables', 'bootstrap'], function($) ...
```

Otherwise require js will look for the file dataTable.js and not the one it needs to retrieve.

Comment: I updated my answer with this change. Thanks @Mario.

Answer (score 0):

Since require 2.1.11 [the wrapShim option](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L86) handle this problem, so you can keep the original source file.

Comment: I spent 5 mn trying this. and it does not work for the require.js seems wrapShim is only for r.js no"?

Comment: Dependencies management is the same before & after optimizing — the wrapShim option works in both cases :-) It seems that there are some limitations on this option, but when I've used it, it has worked without problems.

Comment: I posted an issue on the requirejs github. Let's see how it ends up.  I thought the wrapShim option was only used by the r.js  When you have a look into the require.js js you see nothing related to wrapShim https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/1149