# DataTables is not initializing properly in RequireJS project

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am utilizing the [jQuery DataTables plugin](https://datatables.net/) for a project that uses [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). I have loaded in the DataTables library and initialization script into the RequireJS `app.js` script, and added the appropriate element ID to the table in my template file. I cannot get DataTables to initialize. Seemingly, DataTables and RequireJS do not play well together. I am not seeing any error messages in the console regarding the code below, but it is still not working as intended.

Here is my initialization script:

```
require(["datatables.net"], function() {
$(function() {
// initialize DataTables
$("#example").DataTable({
});
});
});
```

Here is my RequireJS configuration:

```
requirejs.config({
config: {
    //Set the config for the i18n
    //module ID
    i18n: {
        // Change this to en-us to use the strings in nls/en-us for example
        locale: 'en-gb'
    }
},
// "urlArgs": "ts=" + new Date().getTime(), // disable caching - remove in production
"baseUrl": "js/lib",
"paths": {
    "app":                       "../app",
    "jquery":                    "../lib/jquery-2-0-0.min",
    "bootstrap":                 "../lib/bootstrap.min",
    "backbone":                  "../lib/backbone-min",
    "underscore":                "../lib/underscore-min",
    "text":                      "../lib/text.min",
    "store":                     "../lib/store.min",
    "loader":                    "../lib/spin.min",
    "jquery-insertAtCaret":      "../lib/jquery-insertAtCaret",
    "splash-clearAndResetModal": "../lib/splash/clearAndResetModal",
    "splash-utils":              "../lib/splash/utils",
    "splash-proofhq":            "../lib/splash/proofhq",
    "splash-config":             "../config",
    "datatables.net":                "//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min",
    "datatables-js":             "../lib/datatables-js"
},
wrapShim: false,
// Add dependancies to the libs
shim: {
    // "enc-base64": {
    //     deps: ["sha256", "hmac-sha256"]
    // }
}
});
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure jQuery was loading correctly before the initialization?

Comment: Hi @lamelemon - Yes, jQuery is loading correctly.

Comment: Is it possible to create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Have you tried removing the new?

Comment: Hi @theClap - yes, I have tried removing the new. Still does not work.

Comment: In your paths, can you try renaming `"datatables":` to `"datatables.net":`

Comment: @NickyTheWrench When I changed to `datatables.net`, I got this error: require.js:19 TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function(…)

Comment: did you also change `"datatables"` to `"datatables.net"` in the `requirejs()` call?

Comment: @theClap I sure did. Unfortunately, this still does not work. The initialization script is: `requirejs( ["datatables.net"], function() {
  $('#example').dataTable();
} );
`

Comment: Take a look at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pt1o4y42/3/), which is an example of using DataTables with RequireJS - maybe it can help point you in the right direction? Sorry I can't be of further help! :-)

Comment: Does your bootstrap (or any other js files loading prior to datatables for that matter) have a call to $.fn.dataTable in it?  This was a more broad/not quite identical question, but something to look into.  He basically wraps his bootstrap to keep it from being loaded before the datatables js file.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371233/unable-to-load-jquery-plugins-when-using-requirejs-r-js-optimizer#answer-15755464

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I FINALLY was able to get this working. Allan from DataTables helped me out.

Basically, what was happening... there was not anything wrong with the DataTables initialization code as such (as odd as that may sound).

It was running, but at the point it is running, the table was not in the document. The `#example` selector found no elements and therefore, nothing happened. Then the template code in `admin.js` kicks in and puts the table into the DOM - but it happens too late!

What needed to change was initializing the DataTable AFTER the HTML table is in the DOM. This is `done` method in `admin.js`:

```
.done(function() {
$('#js-loading-state').remove();
$('#example').DataTable();
});
```

The `datatables-js.js` file is not required since the loading of the HTML happens asynchronously. I hope this helps someone else with a similar project.

Answer (score 0):

try this in RequireJs config

```
"datatables.net":"..libs/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables",
```

Or try this

```
  "dataTables": "http://datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables",
```

Comment: This did not work. I am getting an error: require.js:19 TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function(…)

Comment: try change datatables.net insted "dataTables

Comment: That still did not work. At this point, I do not believe updating the name will do any good. I have tried many iterations of the name, all of which have not helped me initialize DataTables.

Comment: what exactly in #example

Comment: can i see template file

Comment: https://github.com/erbanach/translation-system template file is `public-static/templates/admin.html`

Answer (score 0):

In `https://github.com/erbanach/translation-system/blob/master/public-static/js/lib/datatables-js.js`, change `$('#example').dataTable();` to `$('#example').DataTable();`, with capital D.

Also, change the first line:

```
require(["jquery", "datatables"], function() {
```

to this:

```
require(["jquery", "datatables"], function($) {
```

Also, don't initialize DataTables with an empty JSON object. Change:

```
$("#example").DataTable({});
```

To this:

```
$("#example").DataTable();
```

Comment: @LizBanach Could you try the change from my edit (add `$` to the anonymous function in that same file)? Sorry but I don't have access to a dev machine and I'm debugging blind

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am now getting a new error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < caused by datatables-js.js. Any thoughts on what could cause this? My updated code is available in the repo, and looks like: `require(["jquery", "datatables"], function($) {
    $(function() {
        // initialize DataTables
        $("#example").DataTable({});
    });
});
`

Comment: @LizBanach Remove the empty braces on your `DataTable` initialization. Change `$("#example").DataTable({});` to `$("#example").DataTable();`

Comment: I am still getting this console error: datatables-js.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <